# Dynamically add controls in Page_Init which loads every time (how to Avoid every controls reloading?)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, asp.net-4.0

I am adding RadDock control and adding its Item Command events which require to be added in Pag_Init. And adding user controls to RadDock.

My problem is that when I have some post back for a specific control page_Init calls which reloads the controls and every control is re-binded every time. I want to avoid control creation every time. And want the specific control's post back should happen.

If I apply `(!IsPostBack)` condition in Page_Init then controls are not loaded and page gets empty.

I am stuck.

Any best practice or work around is acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do something for the RadDock in `Page_Init`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of Telerik's tools, but if they work like regular ASP.NET dynamic controls, you have to add the controls to the control tree on every page load. Populating the controls with data is distinct from adding them to the control tree. If the controls are added correctly so that they are placed in the same way in the control tree as on the previous page visit, and implement ViewState correctly (if needed) the runtime will populate them with data from the posted data and ViewState when a postback occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I added IFrame to RadDock and then gave user control source to IFrame. Now it is working fine, Only the specific control's post back occurs.

Any way, Thanks Jonas